# ImageDataGenerator flow_from_directory with grandchild folder

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, dataset

I have a k-fold train dataset but its structure has a grandchild folder for ex:

```
/monkey
     / howler monkey
         - img1
         - img2
     / japanese macaque
         - img1
         - img2
/dog
     / bulldog
         - img1
         - img2
     / Rottweiler
         - img1
         - img2
```

In this situation when I use `ImageDataGenerator` `flow_from_directory`. Found 8 img exactly but the class has 2, not 4. How can I get 4 classes?

Answer (score 0):

I have this question for a long time and I couldnt find a direct answer using `.flow_from_directory`. What I did instead, was use `.flow_from_dataframe` instead. Where first, I just created a dataframe with the images paths and their corresponding label (in your case howler monkey, japanese macque, etc). You dont actual load the image at any point when making this dataframe.

it would go something like this:

```
images_paths_label = []
for root_class in os.listdir(root_folder):
   temp_class = os.path.join(root_folder, root_class)
   for class in os.listdir(temp_class):
       temp_subclass = os.path.join(temp_class, class)
       for image in os.listdir(temp_subclass):
           temp_img_path = os.path.join(temp_subclass, image)
           images_paths_label.append([temp_img_path, class])

df = pd.DataFrame(images_paths_label, columns = ['image_path', 'label'])

# Now the flow_from_dataframe part
generator = ImageDataGenerator(validation_split = 0.2)
train_generator = generator.flow_from_directory(df, directory = None, x_col = 'image_path', y_col = 'label', seed = 14,...)
```

- Check the indent of the code snippet before using it. I just type it here in stackoverflow.

You are giving `directory = None`, because you are putting an absolute path in the `image_path` column of the dataframe. And a seed is specified because `shuffle= True` by default and it should be true because your dataframe samples are ordered by class. And setting the seed here, allows you to be sure that the validation data will remain the same.

This should give you an overall idea of how to overcome this problem while still using a generator. Tell me if you find any problem.